# JDBC DriverManager driver selection

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have an application which purpose is to support JDBC connections for `jdbc:hive://` and `jdbc:hive2://` protocols. The following code loads the corresponding JDBC drivers for both protocols:

```
private void setDriverClass() ... {
    ...
    Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"); // acceptsURL -> jdbc:hive://
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"); // acceptsURL -> jdbc:hive2://
}
```

As I understand, when a client connection is invoked DriverManager calls accepstURL() method to validate whether the current driver in the index can handle the connection. acceptsURL() normally uses jdbcURL.startsWith method to match the string.

Sometimes I have client connections that uses `jdbc:hive2://` prefix not being established because "invalid jdbcURL" error. It seems like `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` is accepting the `jdbc:hive2://` prefix and throwing the exception --`org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` is shown in the stacktrace--, which is correct since it's acceptsURL is returning false (as I've verified).

My question is: besides acceptsURL is there any other method that DriverManager uses to select the JDBC driver to be used when creating a connection? And, it depends on DriverManager solely or the underlying JDBC driver needs to implement supporting code besides acceptsURL() and the jdbc's basics.

Comment: This is very vague. Can you please tell us what driver you are using and what exception you are getting?

Comment: Hi @GiovanniBotta, I've updated the description. I've used generic since I'm working on different JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

DriverManager relies on JDBC spec (and driver's compliance with it) where it's noted that:

> The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to connect to the given URL.  This will be common, as when the JDBC driver manager is asked to connect to a given URL it passes the URL to each loaded driver in turn.

Hive's JDBC driver violates the contract and throws exception instead which interpreted by DriverManager as "driver understands the URL, but cannot establish connection for some reason". That would be fine in case DriverManager call driver's `acceptsURL()` not only as part of `getDriver(url)`, but also as part of `getConnection(url)` method, but it doesn't.

Comment: I had a similar problem using MySql and Oracle. And eventually I get a MySql malformed URL exception for an Oracle connexion. Might this fault also aplly to MySql Drivers? And how to solve it? Can I just empty the DriverManager for every connexion to make sure it has only the single one I need?

Answer (score 0):

With the newer versions of JDBC, you don't have to load the JDBC driver into memory. The JDBC code will scan your classpath for drivers.

This makes your `setDriverClass` method unnecessary. Just make sure you include the drivers as JARs in your classpath.

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver contains one or more classes that implements the interface java.sql.Driver. [...]
>
> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

(From the [JDBC Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html))